# python-cloudant query error

Tags: python, cloudant

I am using the python-cloudant library, trying to do a query:

```
import cloudant

my_database = client['database']

query = cloudant.query.Query(my_database,selector={'selector': {'$gt': 0}},fields=['doi'])
for doc in query(limit=100, skip=100)['docs']:
    print doc
```

This gives me an error: HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://myurl.com/mydatabase/_find

With this error when I try loading the page in a browser:
{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only POST allowed"}

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have an index on the field named `selector` then this query won't work.

So assuming that you meant to use the primary index which is on the `_id` field then if you change `selector={'selector': {'$gt': 0}}` to `selector={'_id': {'$gt': 0}}` this query should work.

As in:

```
import cloudant

client = cloudant.Cloudant(USER, PWD, account=ACCOUNT)
client.connect()

my_database = client['database']

query = cloudant.query.Query(my_database,selector={'_id': {'$gt': 0}},fields=['doi'])
for doc in query(limit=100, skip=100)['docs']:
    print doc
```